# How to tell is a JavaScript even is going to redirect the page?

Tags: javascript, events

So I' ve got a function that fires on the event listener of all sorts of DOM events: click, keyup, keydown, mousedown, submit, input, etc.

How can I, judging only by the event object, potentially tell if the event will redirect the user to a new page?

If the target property is an anchor tag, I can tell it has a location property, but what if the vent is a mouseover?

I need a definitive way to tell if the event is about to change the location of the page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `onbeforeunload` or `onunload` of the window? Should be much easier if you are only concerned with handling something before the location of the page is changed.

Comment: Can those events be prevented? Isn't there a browser security thing?

Comment: AFAIK they cannot be prevented. The difference is that the onbeforeunload fires before a response from the server, while the unload will not trigger until the server responds. What do you mean by browser security thing, these are just normal DOM events?

Comment: You can prevent a click even but you can't prevent a beforeunload event to prevent js from easily preventing the use from navigating away from the page.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Are you talking about event.preventDefault() or returning false from the event handler? Of course you can alter or prevent the default behavior from an event handler... But that has nothing to do with "a browser security thing". I guess I do not understand your issue well enough.